# Why is the command line file not getting the lines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments

I originally had a program that prompted the user for a file name with `raw_input`, opened and read the file, and performed a few actions with prints.

Now I am interested in getting the file name from command line arguments like this: `C:\Users\MyName\pythonfile.py somenumbers.txt`

When attempting to execute with what you see above ^, the somenumbers.txt file is printed, but no further actions take place on it starting at the line: `for line in file:`.

I am stumped as to why I could perform further actions before when the user was prompted with `raw_input'.

Here is the pertain code with the `raw_input` that I had before where I could print out the whole file (if I wanted to) and perform all actions after `for line in file:`.

```
import sys

#Query the user for a file name 
filename = raw_input("Please enter a file name: ")

integer_list = []

#Open and read the file selected by the user
#Error checking for file
#try:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:

      #try:
        for line in file:
          if line.strip() and not line.startswith("#"):


              integer_list.append(line)


              myset = set(line.split())
              myset_count = len(myset)


              integer_list = line.split(' ')
              result = sum([int(integer_list[i]) != int(integer_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(integer_list)-1)]) + 1

              mylist = list(line.split())
              integer_list = line.split(' ')
 #finally: 
                            #file.close()   #Close the file
```

Now, here is the code that gets the file name from command line (with the command line formatting you see above):

```
import sys
print 'here'

print 'here1'
integer_list = []
print 'here2'
print 'here3'

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
    print(file.read())
    for line in file:
        print 'here4'
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith("#"):          
          integer_list.append(line)
          print 'here5'
          myset = set(line.split())
          myset_count = len(myset)
          print 'here6'
          integer_list = line.split(' ')
          result = sum([int(integer_list[i]) != int(integer_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(integer_list)-1)]) + 1
          mylist = list(line.split())
          integer_list = line.split(' ')
```

I can now input the following with the code involving command line agruments:

```
    here
    here1
    here2
    here3
    This is the file data 
    This is more of the file
```

I am stumped as to why the rest of the code after `for line in file:` will not be executed now.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can have a `try` without an `except` or `finally`. You have two `try`s, no `except`s and only one `finally`

Comment: Also you don't need to close the file in the `finally` block because you're using a context manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print(file.read())
for line in file:
    ...
```

With `file.read()` you have read everything: you are now at the end of the file.

From the end of the file, there are no more lines to be read, hence `for line in file` won't run, as `file` is exhausted.

Either remove the `print(file.read())` line, or rewind the file:

```
print(file.read())
file.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
for line in file:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, from a Python beginner! I appreciate your detailed help, and will keep this in mind for the future. Awesome.